# 10 unique values using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Hello i want to get from my table the first 10 unique values from one column and all the rows that they appear in.

For example i have this table (column 2 isnt null):

```
column 1    column 2
a1        
a1 
a2
a3
a4
a4
a4
a5
a6
a7
a8
a9
a10
```

I want to get all the **rows** that have the first 10 unique values in column 10.

I tried to use

```
SELECT * FROM some_table GROUP BY some_column ORDER BY main_id DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

but its returing to me only 1 row from each unique value.

In my example it will return to me one row from a1, one row from a2... one row from a10.

How can i get all the rows that have first 10 unique values.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery

```
select t1.*
from table t1
inner join (select distinct main_id
            from table
            order by main_id desc
            limit 10) t2
on t1.col10 = t2.main_id
```

Comment: . . This is not guaranteed to work.  You want `(select col1 from table group by col1 order by min(main_id) desc limit 10)`.  Your version first does the distinct, taking an *arbitrary* value of `main_id` with it.

Comment: His question is kind of confusing about which column is which. I suspect the ordering and distinct column are actually the same, I've changed the question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Barmaer. I didnt know about the inner join command. I will read about it and see how to manage it.

Comment: Sigh. If you don't know INNER JOIN, you don't really know SQL. It's the 2nd thing you should learn after WHERE.